# What is the technology behind Dailymile.com

Tags: php

What is the technology behind Dailymile.com? Does it use PHP or Ruby?

Thanks!

Comment: This might an appropriate target for migration to Webapps?

Comment: If it's PHP, they've disabled the http://www.dailymile.com/?=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42 easter egg

Answer (score 3):

Some random poster on their forums said that it's a Ruby On Rails app.

http://www.dailymile.com/forums/general-running/questions/1013